# How to retrieve a result set from a SQLite table using latitude and longitude variables as criteria?

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I need to build a SQLite table that will consist of the following columns:

1. Name
2. Address
3. City
4. ProvinceState
5. PostalZipCode
6. Country
7. PhoneNumber
8. Latitude
9. Longitude

I need to send a request to this table, where I am passing latitude, and longitude variables that have been calculated from the user's position using CLLocation, and retrieve rows that are closest to the one's I am passing in.  However, my problem is:

1. What column type should Latitude, and Longitude be, so that I can pull the relevant rows?  Should the columns be Strings, or something else?  What type should my variables that I am passing in should be?  Should they be Strings, doubles, or something else?  At present, I have them as Strings in my code, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.  This is important because in the case of the longitudinal coordinates, the values will be negative.  How would I take this into account when I make my sql call?
2. At present, the table is quite small.  However, this table will definitely become quite large in the future, and I don't want to retrieve ALL values from the table, but rather, filter out the irrelevant values, and only retrieve those that are necessary.  The way I figure I would do this would be to retrieve those rows whose latitude/longitudinal pairs were numerically closest to the ones I am passing in.  How would I construct a SQL query that would accommodate this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides storing latitude and longitude as double, you'd definitely want to index those fields. However you should be aware of the fact that index operations are most efficient in case of integer fields - and this is an important consideration when it comes to large data volumes.

I guess the following algorithm might help you:

- introduce additional columns:

  - LatitudeIdx int = round(Latitude * ScaleFactor)
  - LongitudeIdx int = round(Longitude * ScaleFactor)
- define value for ScaleFactor which will suite your needs
- define an index (LatitudeIdx, LongitudeIdx)
- query you data using LatiduteIdx and LongitudeIdx values (this will be an fast index lookup operation)

What you achieve with *Idx columns and ScaleFactor is actually breaking your data into cells of equal size. Size of the cell is actually 1/ScaleFactor geo degrees, i.e. roughly 111 km/ScaleFactor.

So when you retrieve the data with particular LatitudeIdx and LongitudeIdx values you're actually getting all points that fall into the cell defined by those values, i.e. filter your data points. After that you calculate distances to the point of interest and select closest one (you can actually do that directly in query and sort by distance to get the point you need in a single pass).

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply, I really appreciate it.  One follow up question, how big should the ScaleFactor be?  Should this be an arbitrary number (e.g. 5)?  Thanks again for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: As always with such things the answer is 'it depends' :-) ScaleFactor defines the size of the cell you're going to use for filtering points in a first turn. For example: if you want to filter out the points that fall withing say 500m of target point, you need to use ScaleFactor = 111 km / (2*500m) = 111

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt reply.  Your approach is something very unique, and not one I considered before as I am very new to iPhone programming and geolocation.  Is it possible for you to clarify further the theory about the scale factor?  I want my iPhone app to present to the user the closest specialty restaurants to where he/she is, and present them to the user in order of closest to furthest.  My SQLite table would contain the latitude/longitude coordinate pairs for each location.  If you could further clarify the concepts that you presented, I would really appreciate it. Thanks Again!

Comment: Do you perhaps have a link that would provide more information about scale factor's as it relates to geolocation?  Thanks again for everything!

Comment: ScaleFactor is just a name for a value - it's not a concept. The name could be 'a' as well as any other. The idea is to switch from processing a lot of float data to int data which is performed way faster. Multiply and drop remainder is a good way (and basically that's what ScaleFactor does).

Comment: So what you're saying is, if I want to retrieve all the points that are within say, 10Km from my location, then I would use a scale factor of 10000, correct? i.e.  111 km/(2*10000).  If that is the case, then calculating the index values for all of the locations shouldn't be a problem.  However, if for example I have the following point: double lat = 37.531058, lon2 = -121.959668; and I want all the points within 10Km of my location, LatIDx would be 0.20829, and LonIDx would be -0.67687.  How would I use these values to retrieve the necessary results? Would would be my SQL query?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  I'm still not quite sure I understand the theory behind your solution in lieu of an example, but you definitely did point me into the right direction, and use your approach to solve my problem.  Thanks again for taking the time to respond.  Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Writing queries in sqlite is similar to writing query in any other SQL language. Based on my understanding of your question, i think you should store latitude and longitude as double.